# Polymorphic Vectors Without Object Slicing [C++]

Tags: c++, containers, polymorphism

I am trying to store a number of objects which are derived from a base class in a `std::array`(or any other container) without object slicing.

The desired output from the code snippet below is:

```
Hi from child1!
Hi from child2!
```

And the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

class Base {
    public:
        void hello() { 
            std::cout << "This shouldn't print\n";
        }
};

class Child1 : public Base {
    public:
        void hello() {
            std::cout << "Hi from child 1!\n";
        }
};

class Child2 : public Base {
    public:
        void hello() {
            std::cout << "Hi from child 2!\n";
        }
};

std::array<std::unique_ptr<Base>, 2> array = {std::make_unique<Child1>(Child1()), std::make_unique<Child2>(Child2()) };
 
int main() {
    for (auto &i : array) {
        i->hello();
    }
}
```

The output I actually get from the code is:

```
This shouldn't print
This shouldn't print
```

Obviously the derived objects have been sliced. Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: They are not sliced, you store them as pointers. But you forgot to make the function `virtual`.

Comment: @OP -- This has all the earmarks of trying to use Java or similar language as a model in writing C++ code.  Please don't do this.  If you continue down this path, your code will suffer from one or more of these 3 things:  1) The code is buggy.  2) The code will be inefficient in terms of the coding and the running of the program.  3) The code will look weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: Thank you, that's solved my problem. I had made the function virtual earlier but had mistakenly done `std::make_unique<Base>(Child1())` which, of course, did not compile since Base is a virtual class.

Comment: @Ryan "*which, of course, did not compile since Base is a virtual class*" - that is not why it didn't compile. In fact, that statement does compile fine for me, whether `Base` has virtual methods or not. It just doesn't do what you think it does. It does not return a `unique_ptr<Base>` pointing to a `Child1` object. It returns a `unique_ptr<Base>` pointing to a `Base` object that was passed a temporary `Child1` object to its constructor.

Comment: I think you are confusing *virtual* and *pure virtual*. Having a pure virtual function in class makes it *abstract* (i.e., you cannot create an isntance of it). Having any virtual function makes class polymorphic, but not necessarily abstract.

Comment: You also might be confusing _virtual functions_ with _virtual base classes_. To keep things simple, unless you're working with diamond inheritance, you should not write `class Child : virtual Base`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Obviously the derived objects have been sliced.

Actually, no.  They are not being sliced.  You are doing the correct thing in storing base-class pointers to derived-class objects in your array.

No, the code doesn't work the way you want, not because of object slicing, but because you simply did not mark `hello()` as `virtual` in `Base` and as `override` in the derived classes.  So, when you call `i->hello()` inside your loop, there is no polymorphic dispatch being performed.

Also, you are using `std::make_unique()` incorrectly.  The parameters of `make_unique<T>()` are passed as-is to the constructor of `T`. In this case, you are copy-constructing your `Child1`/`Child2` classes from temporary `Child1`/`Child2` objects, which is not necessary.  You can get rid of the temporaries.

You are also lacking a `virtual` destructor in `Base`.  Which will cause *undefined behavior* when your array goes out of scope and the `unique_ptr`s try to call `delete` on their `Base*` pointers.  Only the `Base` destructor will be called, but not the `Child1`/`Child2` destructors.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() = default;

        virtual void hello() { 
            std::cout << "This shouldn't print\n";
        }
};

class Child1 : public Base {
    public:
        void hello() override {
            std::cout << "Hi from child 1!\n";
        }
};

class Child2 : public Base {
    public:
        void hello() override {
            std::cout << "Hi from child 2!\n";
        }
};
 
int main() {
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Base>, 2> array = {
        std::make_unique<Child1>(),
        std::make_unique<Child2>()
    };

    for (auto &i : array) {
        i->hello();
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/744WrQ)